# Scale following the location of another object

Tags: transforms, parent, scale

I am making an animation and I need the z scale of an object to follow the z location of another object. Can anyone help me with that, please?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You can try using the transformation constraint, similar to [this answer](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/139109/935).

Answer (score 1):

You have to *drive* one object's scale factor in the Z axis, by the other object's location in the Z axis. This is how you would implement it.

If object A is to be scaled based on object B's z coordinate:

1. Animate object B's z location by inserting keyframe points appropriately.
2. With object A selected, in the object properties (or the transform toolbox, press 'N' in the 3D View window), hover over the scale Z box and right-click: select add driver.
3. Configure the driver menu as follows:

   - Driver Settings -> Type = Scripted Expression
   - Expression is the scale value. In the example shown in the screenshot, we add to `var` (location Z coordinate) `1.0`.
   - Under `Add Input Variable`, on the drop-down menu, select `Transform Channel`; `Object` should be your object B; under `Type`, select `Z Location`; finally, set the coordinate system (in the example below is the world space).

Now, object A's scale factor on the Z axis will be equal to object B's location in the global Z axis plus one (`expression = var + 1.0`) .

[image]

[image]